# だったら as an interjection

Tags: grammar, particles, tense, past

> だったらさ！

だった is the completed tense of だ, ら is a rough indicator, and さ is an assertion. The completed existential verb with the rough indicator would seem to say something like "Things having been like so, indicates...", or "If that's the case, then..."

Would the assertion change it to something like "It is indicated that things are like so!" or "It is the case!"?

Comment: さ is just a filler. It would be something like "In that case, well,. ..."

Comment: How do I reconcile the ending filler with the exclamation, then?
"In that case, well!" (Or any other filler) seems odd to me.

Comment: Context...?
Without context though, if it's used as an interjection, I'd say it's something like, "But that means...!" in English. Where the person just discovered something new and is making a sudden, shocking conclusion from it. Just what it sounds like to me.

Comment: It's fine, just like saying "Well then!" is fine. I can't really tell you what だったらさ means for every case because it depends on context. Anyway, it's still filler, although to be frank だったらさ！ sounds really odd.

Comment: "ら is a rough indicator". I think you might be misunderstanding this one. ら means "if" here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(だったら means "if it is, then".)

さ as in だったらさ is never a sentence ending particle. So it's always a filler.

さ as a sentence ender can appear (1) after a terminal form of verbs or adjectives, and (2) after a noun in the position of the predicate.

e.g. (1) なんとか なるさ。 (2) （私は）探偵さ。