# What does ってさ mean?

Tags: grammar

What does ってさ mean in this situation:

[image: ってさ example]

Comment: Any good dictionary would list both 「って」 and 「さ（あ）」.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [デジタル大辞泉「って」](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/147762/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6/):

> って
>   2⃣［係助］名詞、名詞的な語に付く。
>   １ ある事柄を話題として取り上げて示す意を表す。…は。…というのは。「あなたって親切な人ね」「彼ってだれのこと」

って
2⃣ binding particle. Attaches to a noun or noun-like word.
1 Used to introduce something as a topic. Means ～は or ～というのは. eg 「あなたって親切な人ね」（≂「あなたは親切な人ね」）「彼ってだれのこと」(≂「彼というのはだれのこと？」)

So 「こういう人**って**さぁ...」 in your example means 「こういう人**は**さぁ...」 "People like that are / A person like this is ..." or 「こういう人**というのは**さぁ...」 "People like that are (generally) ...". ～って is quite colloquial and informal.

---

The さ(ぁ) is an interjectory particle (間投助詞), or a filler. You could refer to [this dictionary entry](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/84242/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%95/) (See 2⃣［間助］), or see these threads: [What does さあ (saa) mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14922/9831) ・ [だったら as an interjection](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30021/9831)